# Android Service won't run from AlarmManager

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a problem with running a service  from Alarm manager.

I am building an app that notifies the owner on the namedays of his facebook friends. It all works nicely, but the notification won't show up.

I've set up an AlarmTask that creates the PendingIntent and sets the AlarmManager, like this:

```
public void run() {


    // Request to start are service when the alarm date is upon us

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
    intent.putExtra("notifyID", ID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, ID, intent, 0);

    // Sets an alarm - note this alarm will be lost if the phone is turned off and on again
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

The ID is specific for every nameday.

Now in my NotifyService, I have set up these:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("NOTIFICATION SERVICE onCreate()");
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    System.out.println("INTENT RECIEVED: " + intent + " " + flags + " " + startId);

    // If this service was started by out AlarmTask intent then we want to show our notification
    if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false)){
        int ID = intent.getIntExtra("notifyID", -1);
        showNotification(ID);
    }
    // We don't care if this service is stopped as we have already delivered our notification
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Both the methods are executed once when I start the app, but when the notification should come up, nothing happens.

Is there a way to test if the AlarmManager really executes the PendingIntent?
Should I rather use IntentService? Why/how?

Thanks a lot.

I tried to change it to BroadcastReciever, looking like this:

```
public class NotificationBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("BROADCAST RECIEVED");

}
```

}

The AlarmTask bit is changed to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("NotificationBroadcast");
    intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
    intent.putExtra("notifyID", ID);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), ID, intent, 0);
     System.out.println("date for notification: " + date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "." + date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "." + date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
     System.out.println("epoch time in milils: " + date.getTimeInMillis());
    // Sets an alarm - note this alarm will be lost if the phone is turned off and on again
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and relevant manifest part looks like this:

```
  <receiver 
        android:name="cz.cvut.kubispe2.jmeniny.NotificationBroadcastReciever" 
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="NotificationBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I checked if the date that is to be set is equal to the epoch time and it is, but still, the onRecieve method is never called.

Comment: Did you want to add some delay in  am.set() ? 
date.getTimeInMillis() + DELAY_IN_MILLIS

Comment: I am trying to start the notification at a specified date (here date is a Calendar instance bearing the information about the notification), so I don't think a delay would be necessary

Comment: From your description, the service starts when the app starts, which seems like the time is now or in the past, and not in the future. Otherwise why does the service start when the app starts ? Add log messages, your code looks ok.

Comment: That might be possible. Is there any way to restart the service though? I want to have more notifications throughout the year, not just one.

Comment: Sure. The service, when done, can schedule a new pendingIntent via the alarm manager for some time later, and the close itself.

Comment: So, do I need to close the service before it can be called again by another alarm manager pending intent? Does that mean that when the service onStartCommand is called on the beginning of the app, does it block itself from recieving other intents?

Answer (score 2):

> Both the methods are executed once when I start the app, but when the notification should come up, nothing happens.

`_WAKEUP` alarms are only guaranteed to wake up the device if they route to a `BroadcastReceiver`, not a `Service`. So long as what you are doing is very short (1-2 milliseconds), you can safely do that work in `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`. The work you are presently doing in your `Service` would qualify.

Beyond that, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to confirm that your alarm is scheduled for when you think it is.

> Should I rather use IntentService?

It would certainly be a better option than a regular `Service`, which you are leaking in your current implementation. However, the `_WAKEUP` limitation still holds, which is why [I wrote `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), to help bridge the gap. Again, though, with the current limited work you are doing, just using a `BroadcastReceiver` should suffice.

Comment: well, I'm not really sure how to read the dumpsys log. This is an example record from the log, can you help me understand what it means?

RTC_WAKEUP #35: Alarm{44e31838 type 0 cz.cvut.kubispe2.jmeniny}

    type=0 when=1369227635942 repeatInterval=0 count=0

    operation=PendingIntent{44ea5ac8: PendingIntentRecord{44f34048 cz.cvut.kubispe2.jmeniny broadcastIntent}}

Comment: @PetrKubišta: You may wish to test on a newer device or emulator. The `when` you are seeing is probably milliseconds-since-the-Unix-epoch. Newer environments should format that more like `when=+11h1m38s567ms` showing hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds until the event should occur.

Comment: I tried changing it to the broadcast reciever as you suggested, but there is still no change in the functionality. I updated the code to the question. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Also, I did find the alarm in the dumpsys that I set for the testing, it was set to the correct time and the intent was to broadcastIntent, as it should be, I assume.

Comment: @PetrKubišta: I would remove the `<intent-filter>` from the `BroadcastReceiver`, remove the `android:exported="false"` (not needed once you remove the `<intent-filter>`), and use an explicit `Intent` (`new Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReciever)`) for the `PendingIntent`. Here is a sample application demonstrating this, albeit using a `WakefulIntentService` rather than merely a `BroadcastReceiver`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Wakeful

Answer (score 0):

try using application context.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context.getApplicationContext(), ID, intent, 0);
```

And work with android [logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html). Then you will see if it's running in your console

Comment: I tried the application context, but it still isn't working. Also, I can see the System.out in my Eclipse LogCat. I know it's not very androidy, but I don't have much time and changing it would take some. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I finally resolved it, I used the broadcast reciever, and found out where the error was - Calendar takes the month argument from 0 to 11, instead of 1-12, which I thought, since all the other arguments are dealt with normally. So I was just putting up a notification for the end of May, instead of today, when testing.

Anyway, thank you all for help, it was very appreciated.